Trunc Function Not Specifying Decimals
I have the following in my table:
create table example (

     col_a int4,
     col_b int4,
     average_col = numeric


)

col_a = 309
col_b = 16

309 / 16 = 19.3125

When I do the following, I only get 19. Not (19.0, or 19.3125, 19.3):
TRUNC((col_a/col_b),1) = 19

What am I doing wrong?

Not reading the docs Math functions/operators: numeric_type / numeric_type → numeric_type Division (for integral types, division truncates the result towards zero) 5.0 / 2 → 2.5000000000000000 5 / 2 → 2

Integers, floats, and numerics are stored differently and their math is different. This is a fundamental thing with computers, computers don't do math like we do. Because you're dividing integers, Postgres only does integer math. 309/16 is 19.
You need to cast at least one integer to a numeric (not a float, trunc with a second argument takes a numeric) then divide.
select trunc(309::numeric/16,1)

Demonstration

Thank you for the well types explanation with demonstration and not just linking me to documentation. This makes sense. I understand now.

@ChickenSandwichNoPickles You're welcome. This is a "don't know enough to know where to look in the docs" problem. Computers aren't good at math, they're just very fast.
